# 404 Issue Getting Started in Heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku

When trying to make my first push to Heroku with `git push heroku master`, I run into a 404 issue installing `MySQL-Connector-Python`. Any ideas on how I can get around this?

### Log:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing runtime (python-2.7.8)
-----> Installing dependencies with pip
       Downloading/unpacking CherryPy==3.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u52278/CherryPy/setup.py) egg_info for package CherryPy
           
       Downloading/unpacking Django==1.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u52278/Django/setup.py) egg_info for package Django
           
       Downloading/unpacking Flask==0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u52278/Flask/setup.py) egg_info for package Flask
           
           warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
       Downloading/unpacking Flask-KVSession==0.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
         Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u52278/Flask-KVSession/setup.py) egg_info for package Flask-KVSession
           
           no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
       Downloading/unpacking Jinja2==2.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
         Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u52278/Jinja2/setup.py) egg_info for package Jinja2
           
       Downloading/unpacking MySQL-Connector-Python==1.1.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
         MySQL-Connector-Python an externally hosted file and may be unreliable
         HTTP error 404 while getting http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-1.1.5.zip#md5=667f1ebccb8a3c3ccbfb54e73016ce14 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysql-connector-python/)
       Cleaning up...
       Exception:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
           status = self.run(options, args)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
           requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
           do_download,
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
           self.session,
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 547, in unpack_http_url
           resp.raise_for_status()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 795, in raise_for_status
           raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
       HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found
       
       Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

Comment: looks to me like it is trying to download a zip file that is no longer supported on the mysql cdn site: http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-1.1.5.zip#md5=667f1ebccb8a3c3ccbfb54e73016ce14 And hence the 404

Comment: I would try one of the newer versions that are still available: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Comment: Have you tried adding the `--allow-external MySQL-Connector-Python` line to your `requirements.txt`, just before the line `MySQL-Connector-Python==1.1.5` ?